# Is it possible to specify symbology of a shapefile in R?

Tags: arcmap, r, shapefile, symbology

I am creating shapefiles from rasters (Myraster) in R using:

```
TESTPOLY<-rasterToPolygons(Myraster,dissolve = TRUE)
```

Then I write it to a shapefile

```
shapefile(TESTPOLY,"TESTPOLYWGS84.shp")
```

I have read this shapefile into ESRI's ArcMap and I can change the symbology of the attribute (maximum temperature) to 'graduated colours' using a chosen colour ramp. I can also remove the outline of each of the polygons (which makes the map look 'nicer').

My problem is that i have to create a large amount of these shapefiles and I want to automate the symbology changes in R. Is that possible? I see in ArcMap, that it is possible to use the symbology from one layer for another. In principle, could I carry out my symbology changes in Arcmap, then 'copy' the formatting and use it in R? I realise that this is not a reproducible example, but I haven't found any information about doing this in the usual 'stack' channels.

Comment: Does Arcmap let you save the symbology to a file? I work with QGIS, and there you can save the symbology as an XML file, so its possible to create symbology files by code from R to go with any spatial data set. You do still have to load the layer and the symbology into QGIS (although I think there's way to do this by packing it all in a GeoPackage or some other file...). Does Arcmap work with SLD standard files?

Comment: @Spacedman I can't save an xml file though from ArcGIS, because once I have modified the sample file symbology, that new symbology is not saved to the shapefile itself? And it seems like I can only download the xml in ArcCatalogue for existing shapefiles.

Comment: There's nothing in the shapefile standard that permits storing symbology. Any connection between symbology and shapefile will be custom to the GIS. For example, if you have a foo.shp/dbf/prj and a QGIS foo.qml style file, then reading the shapefile in qgis will load the foo.qml and style the layer. If you change the symbology in QGIS you do have to manually save to the qml file again.